# JavaFX wont import after JRE 7u5 install on OSX Lion

Tags: macos, java

I installed JDK 7u5 to get Javafx on my OSX machine running Lion so I could use an mp3 playing code.

But, when I do:

```
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
```

It says "The import javafx cannot be resolved".
I have set JDK 7 as my preferred JDK in Applications/Utilities/Java Preferences
I also added the JDK to eclipse, and have it set as the JDK for this project.

I have installed and uninstalled the JDK a few times.

Comment: This looks like an environmental issue - the javafx runtime is not loaded by the compiler - if you want to make reference to it then add the jfxrt.jar file to the libraries being referenced - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxrt.jar